# Apply filter to multiple rows in R and use it as a dataset into a lapply function

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a dataset with approx 10.000 rows and each row. This is the dataset, but with 10k rows.

```
dat <- data.frame(speed=c(1,2,3,4,5),cycle=c(1,2,2,3,4))
```

Is there any way to subset to for each different cycle for instance for cycle=1 I want to have one dataframe (for instance, dat_cycle1) and then I want to convert it to matrix it and use it as an input to a another function.

i tried something like

`for (i in 1:nrow(dat) {dat[i] <- filter(dat, cycle==i)}`

but not working.

Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: I think you are looking for `split`, i.e. `split(dat, dat$cycle)`

Comment: Well, it works :) Thank you!!!